# Implementing Eddystone hardware

Tags: beacon, google-beacon-platform

What sort of hardware can I use to implement Eddystone beacons?

I don't want I manufactured hardware like estimote or radius networds hardware.

Answer (score 1):

For Eddystone-UID and Eddystone-URL, you can use:

- Any hardware based on a Bluetooth 4.0 chip.  Manufacturers include Nordic, TI, and Blue Giga make modules and systems on a chip, but you will need tooling from them to develop firmware.
- An Android 6.0+ device that supports BLE advertising.  Code is written in Java.
- Any Linux computer including a Raspberry Pi that supports the BlueZ stack and has a Bluetooth 4.0+ device.

You cannot use:

- An iOS device.  The operating system prevents advertising

Comment: Tks,What a cheapest hardware can I use to implement Eddystone SDK ?

Comment: The modules and chips from all manuacturers are similarly cheap, only a few dollars if bought in quantity.  Your decision on which to choose should probably be based on toolsets and difficulty of developing the software.